# Regex: non-word-char preceded by space or at the beginning of a line

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror

I'm trying to match `@`'s that are preceeded by nothing or whitespace like in the following example:

```
@one
    @two 
    who@three
    /@four
```

My approach is `(^|\s)@`, but this captures `one two three four`. `\s@` only captures `two`. How do I get `one two`, without getting `three four`?

If it's relevant, all `@`'s are succeeded by a letter.

Comment: @mickmackusa It's for Codemirror using JavaScript. Pardon my ignorance if that's essential information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `^\s*@` ? That is, start of line followed by zero or more whitespace then @. (Note, different laguanges have different regex rules)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

`/^ *@(.+)/`  #allow zero or more spaces before `@` then start matching everything until a newline character.

[Javascript Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mnCklT/2)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use lookbehind, this should work (not supported in native javascript):

```
(?<=\s|^)@
```